# Images won't display properly on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I have a site that I am trying to make more mobile-friendly (http://realnewsline.com/). The problem I am having is that the three main images at the top of the website get cut off on mobile devices and 1 or two of them become impossible to view. Is there any way I can fix this either in Wordpress or with some CSS? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `.image-wrap` divs have an inline style attribute setting the width to 300px. If you remove that, the images will scale to fit on the device.

To avoid the columns disappearing off the screen when it becomes small, you can make them wrap to become rows. Currently, the `.featured-wrap` elements have a width  set to 33% (via `body #wrapper #featured .featured-wrap`) and 100% (in `.featured-wrap`). I would suggest using the `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` property on their parent element (`#featured`), giving the `.featured-wrap` elements an absolute with (say 300px, make sure to remove those other width properties).

Here is some more info on the flex display mode: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ I find it very useful.